# Wordpress Job Manager Pagination Issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jobs

I am using the Wordpress Jobs Manager plugin. It all works great except the pagination feature. When enabled, the pagination buttons just redirect the user to the homepage instead of to the paginated page of results. As far as i can tell this is a problem with permalinks but i wondered if anyone had a workaround as i cannot use the standard permalinks on my site.

Does anyone know of any possible fixes? Its a custom built theme.

Thanks for you help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its a long time since you posted, but i had this issue today and came across your post.

I did some investigating and found it to be a problem with the way wordpress was dealing with the rewrites for canonical redirects.

I did a search on the internet and found the following post on wordpress.stackexchange.com by Celine Garel which deals with this situation for custom post types, i just changed it to work with a page.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134339/pagination-on-custom-post-type-not-working-if-permalinks-set-to-rewrite-url

Add this to your themes function file,

```
    add_filter( 'redirect_canonical','custom_disable_redirect_canonical' ); 
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ){
    if ( is_page('Your_job_list_page') ) $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

This fixed it for me. Hope it helps you or anybody else.

Comment: This is really cool - thank you. However, i notice that this function really messes up the order of jobs and they even change order each time you visit the page. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i did not see this comment or get notification, i'll have a look into it. I have to say i did not notice this behavior.